# Fore color of a disabled button on IE6 and above

Tags: asp.net, html, css

How can i change the fore color of the asp button on disabled mode for IE6 and above

Comment: First of all, if you can help it, drop support for IE6, even Microsoft doesn't support it anymore. Start with IE7 and everything you do will get easier.

Answer (score 0):

**[Reference](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/disabled/)**

### CSS

```
[disabled]#DisabledButton
{
    color: #933;
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

---

### Mark Up

```
<asp:Button ID="DisabledButton" runat="server" Text="Hello Guest" 
                                                      Enabled="false" />
```